# Simplify simple fractions after Hospital's rule

Tags: limits, fractions

I'm having trouble simplifying the result of complicated limits which contain mutliple fractions. I understand this is basic math level, but i find it difficult to find exercices to practice that specific problem.

So assuming my start limit goes like this

$$\lim_{x\to1} \frac 1 {ln(x)} - \frac {1} {(x-1)^2}$$

Form : $\infty$ - $\infty$

I put both on the same denominator

$$\lim_{x\to1} \frac {(x-1)^2 - ln (x)} {ln(x)*(x-1)^2} $$

Form : $\frac 0 0$

Hospital rule

$$\lim_{x\to1} \frac {2(x-1)- \frac 1 x} { \frac 1 x*(x-1)^2+ln(x)*2(x-1))}$$

Now i don't know if i can just cancel both $ \frac 1 x$ since there is + and -. Same goes for the $2(x-1)$.

I know that i can transform the $ \frac 1 x * (x-1)^2$ in $\frac {(x-1)^2} {x}$ but this seems like extra steps.

Thanks!

Comment: I would get rid of the compound fraction action first by multiplying top and bottom by $x$.

Comment: The first form is $\infty - \infty$.

Comment: Fixed the first form, thanks! For the compound fraction, could you explain a bit more?

Comment: I would now inspect what happen if $x\to 1^-$ and $x\to 1^+$.

Comment: You most certainly can *not* factor through a sum!  um, why aren't you plugging in X = 1.  You get -1/0 so the limit diverges.

Comment: Note that a tiny bit below $1$, and also a tiny bit above $1$, the after L'Hospital denominator is small positive. And the numerator is close to $-1$. Lesson:  simplifying algebraically may not be necessary, *looking* may do the job.

Comment: @fleablood As far as I see the limit is $-\infty$

Comment: Yes, that's what I get to.  But I avoid terms like "limit is infinity" for "limit doesn't exist"/diverges/tends to negative infinity.

Comment: @fleablood Ah O.K.

Comment: You should check for the right hand limit and left hand limit. I give you the Wolfram generated result here.
$$\lim _{ x\xrightarrow { } 1^{ + } }{ (\frac { 1 }{ \ln { x } } -\frac { 1 }{ ({ x-1 })^{ 2 } } )=\infty } $$
$$\lim _{ x\xrightarrow { } 1^{ - } }{ (\frac { 1 }{ \ln { x } } -\frac { 1 }{ ({ x-1 })^{ 2 } } )=-\infty } $$

Comment: I know that I can calculate the limit by switching the value of x in this specific case, but a lot of times I need to simplify big fractions that seem to have stuff in common but I can't because of the sums. Which is what I need help on. In this case, my teacher simplified and got : 
$$ \frac {-1} {(x-1)^2+ ln x * 2(x-1)}$$

Comment: @Maude: If so, the simplification was not technically correct.